# __block variable returns nil on method call

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, objective-c-blocks

I have a method which has block string variable which is passed to retrieve API data inside block function.
However it returns nil.
On debugging the addressPlace has nil value.

```
 - (NSString *)getAddressForPlaceAPI:(double)latitudePassed longitude:(double)longitudePassed
 {
    __block NSString * addressPlace = nil;
    NSString *url = @"";
    url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@lat=%@&lng=%@",kGeoCodeURL, [NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitudePassed],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", longitudePassed]];
   [WebServiceObj callWebServiceGET_withAPIName:url withParam:nil withCompletion:^(BOOL isSuceess, NSDictionary *response)
   {
         if(isSuceess)
         {
                 addressPlace = [[response valueForKey:KEY_RESULTS][0] valueForKey:KEY_FORMATTEDADDRESS];
                 NSLog(@"ADDRESSPP*** = %@",addressPlace);

         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"FAIL API = %s","FAIL");
         }
 }];
return addressPlace;
 }
```

Any idea on why this may be happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is method `callWebServiceGET_withAPIName` works in an asynchronous way. So before it returns into completion handler, your code will reach at the end of the function like and returns addressPlace as nil.

To solve that, you should also pass a block in the argument of the method `getAddressForPlaceAPI`. So whenever your success block executes once `callWebServiceGET_withAPIName` returns the value, you can throw the value back to your parent block.

Comment: Can you tell me how to pass block in the method?

Comment: just see how callWebServiceGET_withAPIName method is implemented. You need to do same for your method.